# SSAS Dynamic Security on Parent Child Hierachy

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm using the following MDX Query to define the allowed member set in a dynamic security role over a parent child hierachy:

```
Generate(
    NonEmpty (
        [Business Unit].[Business Unit Key].[Business Unit Key].members,
        (
            [Measures].[AD Account Business Unit Count],
            StrToMember("[AD Account].[AD Account Name].["+Username()+"]")
        )
    ), {
        LinkMember (
            [Business Unit].[Business Unit Key].CurrentMember,
            [Business Unit].[Business Units]
        )
    }
)
```

The MDX query returns as expected when I run it in SQL, and when I look at the 'Basic' tab in the role the correct attributes of the hierachy are selected automatically... all good.

However when I process and view this hierachy in the cube I can still see all of the attributes of the hierachy as if the dynamic security role isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the browser was just being buggy for some reason, if I process the cube and connect via Excel for example then everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Could you plea try to place the same code in default member, The dynamic security with the security level of both allowed and default members. Please let me know the solution